# Не удается сделать регистрацию через google-login кнопку, ругается на куки

Tags: oauth, google-oauth2

До этого работало нормально на https://gradup.org

после того, как пересели на https://gradup.io начались проблемы с регистрацией через эту кнопку, не думаю, что это как-то связано, а вдруг.

Ошибка

```
{error: "idpiframe_initialization_failed", details: "Cookies are not enabled in current environment."}
index.jsx:133 {error: "popup_closed_by_user"}
```

Попапка сама по себе закрывается,
заметила, что на многих платформах не работает логин и сайнап через гугл, если открывается iframe, а на stackoverflow он открывает в отдельном окне и срабатывает.

Подскажите, кто сталкивался или как сделать регистрацию и логин через гугл, как на стэковерфлоу?

Перепробовала многое.